# vector acceleration question

Tags: vectors, physics, kinematics

The question goes: A rifle is fired with angle of elevation $36^{\circ}$. What is the muzzle speed if the maximum height of the bullet is 1600ft?

I ignored the x-component and cared only y-component.

position vector is $$r_y(t) = t(V_{\circ}\cos36^{\circ}-\frac{1}{2}gt^2)j$$

And I have to find a derivative form, which is a velocity $$r'_y(t)=V_{\circ}\cos36^{\circ}-gt$$ and set it equal to zero because at the maximum height the velocity is 0.

So all in all, $t=\frac{V_{\circ}}{g}\cos36^{\circ}$ and I insert this value into the position funtion, and comes out to be $$\frac{2(V_{\circ}\cos36^{\circ})^2-(V_{\circ}\cos36^{\circ})^2}{2g}=487.68m (1600ft)$$

And $V_{\circ}$ comes out to be $120.84m$ or $396ft$. But the answer in solution says to be $544ft$. Where did I do wrong?

Comment: can you explain the first equation, it's confusing.

Comment: It is the y component of the "projectile of the bullet". I am ignoring the x component.

Comment: the t outside of the parenthesis threw me off, but it seems it's a typo.

Comment: Yeah, well it is not a typo actually. The real typo is $r(y)$. I should have used $r_y(t)$. y component of vector position function. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

$$r(y) = (\color{red}tV_{\circ}\color{red}\sin36^{\circ}-\frac{1}{2}gt^2)j$$

$$t=\frac{V_{\circ}}{g}\color{red}{\sin}36^{\circ}$$

$$\frac{2(V_{\circ}\color{red}\sin36^{\circ})^2-(V_{\circ}\color{red}\sin36^{\circ})^2}{2g}=487.68m (1600ft)$$

$$V_0 \approx \frac{\sqrt{487.68 (2g)}}{\sin 36^\circ}\times 3.28 \text{feet}$$

Comment: Stupid mistake... lost quite a long time for this question. Thanks for your answer.